# Is Firefox storing javascript files even if all caches are off?

Tags: firefox

Is Firefox storing javascript files in cache even if all settings says to not store any data ?

I sometimes realize that I have to clear the cache to load the javascript files again.

This usually doesn't occur with css or html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be NO, YES and SOMETIMES. Here is a discussion of javascript caching on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414/force-javascript-file-refresh-on-client)

The only way to *ensure* (cross browser) that a fresh version of the file is loaded seems to be to change the name of the file ie. use `myjsfile_v123.js` instead of `myjsfile.js`

Answer (score 1):

If you set the variable network.http.use-cache to false no css / js files will be stored in cache. Read here more [Prevent Firefox to load css/js from cache](http://wiki.nisi.ro/2011/03/prevent-firefox-to-load-cssjs-from-cache/)